# gcm causes large battery usage

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, battery

I have a simple Android app that does not do anything special except receiving and showing GCM notifications and - then - opening the browser (when a notification is clicked on).

GCM is configured newely as described in the current documentation. The browser is based on the class `WebViewClient`.

I have noticed that this app consumes 4 or 5 times more battery as any other app installed on my phone. As far as I can understand the `BroadcastReceiver` is always running which can cause such an extremely high battery usage.

Is there any may to reduce it? Sometimes my smartphone gets really hot without any activity from my side.

The fragment of my Manifest about GCM:

```
 <receiver
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver"
        android:exported="true"
        android:persistent="true"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
            <action android:name="my.package" />
            <category android:name="my.package" />
        </intent-filter>

 </receiver>
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the best that you can do is to implement GCM (Google Cloud Messaging) using pushing instead of polling.

In this way you will be able to get a "tickle" when something new happened and you will know when ask to the server for datas.

Comment: how can I configurate it?
I use already GCM. where should I write the thing aboud publishing mode?

Comment: @user2957954 https://possiblemobile.com/2013/09/push-dont-poll-how-to-use-gcm-to-update-app-data/ check out this.